# print prime number from a to b and a to b is the value enter by user using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried this but only from 1 to 50 or 1 to 100 prime numbers are obtained.
How should I properly find out the prime number. Which are asked by users?

```
    <h1>enter the no.</h1><input type="text" id="limit">
    <h1>enter the no.</h1><input type="text" id="limit2">
    <button onclick="fun()">Submit</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function fun() {
                var i = limit;
                var j = limit2; 
                limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;
                limit2 = document.getElementById('limit2').value;
                for (i = limit; i <= limit2; i++) {
                    c = 0;

                    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                        if (i % j == 0) {
                            c++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (c == 2) {
                        document.getElementById("result").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', i + '<br>');
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
```

Comment: I highly recommend reading this article:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Some_Basic_and_Inefficient_Prime_Number_Generating_Algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the corrections below

```js
function fun() {
  /*var i = limit;*/
  /*var j = limit2;*/
  var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;
  var limit2 = document.getElementById('limit2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.innerHTML = "Result: ";
  for (var i = limit; i <= limit2; i++) {
    var prime = true;
    /* set j = 2 and NOT j = 1 */
    for (var j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (prime) {
      result.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', i + ','); /* replaced <br/> with , to avoid page scroll */
    }
  }
}
fun(); /* test pupose only */
```

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1>enter the no.</h1><input type="text" id="limit" value="12">
<h1>enter the no.</h1><input type="text" id="limit2" value="55">
<button onclick="fun()">Submit</button>
<div id="result">Result:</div>
```

Comment: It seem not working only displaying the prime number between 12 to 55 only

Comment: yes sir I clicked on submit, as clicked on submit button only display prime number from 12 to 55, if changing the value I don't getting the answer

Comment: thank you sir its working its very helpful for me thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need to check till N for verifying whether its prime. Check up to sqrt(N) that is adequate. This algrithm will take a long time to execute for large numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The text inserted inside an input is of type string , so you need to convert them to a number. Note the use of `+` `document.getElementById("limit").value`. The `+` convert a string to number.

The fill range function inside `fun` creates a new array starting from the the value inserted in the first text box upto the value inserted in second text box.

The array `fill` function will be used to create an array of length `end-start+1` and initially filled with `undefined`. The `map` function will then create another array but `undefined` will be replaced by consecutive values.
`filter` is used to return only prime numbers

```js
function fun() {
  const fillRange = (start, end) => {
    return Array(end - start + 1)
      .fill().map((item, index) => start + index)
      .filter((number) => {
        for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
          if (number % i === 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
  };
  let lowerRange = +document.getElementById("limit").value;
  let upperRange = +document.getElementById("limit2").value
  const primeNums = fillRange(lowerRange, upperRange);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = primeNums.join('<br/>')
}
```

```html
<h1>enter the no.</h1><input type="text" id="limit">
<h1>enter the no.</h1><input type="text" id="limit2">
<button onclick="fun()">Submit</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: sorry sir I don't understand the script as i am beginner

Answer (score 1):

If you want the fast implementation of the wiki link you provided in the question, here is the javascript for the same:

```js
function getPrimesSuperFast(m, n) {
  
    // Eratosthenes algorithm to find all primes under n
    var array = [], upperLimit = Math.sqrt(n), output = [];

    // Make an array from 2 to (n - 1)
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array.push(true);
    }

    // Remove multiples of primes starting from 2, 3, 5,...
    for (var i = 2; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
        if (array[i]) {
            for (var j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
                array[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // All array[i] set to true are primes
    for (var i = m; i < n; i++) {
        if(array[i]) {
            output.push(i);
        }
    }

    return output;
}

function getPrimes() {
  
  var a = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var b = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  var result = getPrimesSuperFast(a, b);
  document.getElementById("res").value = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1">
<input type="number" id="num2">
<button id="primes" onClick="getPrimes()">Get Primes</button>
<hr>
<textarea id="res" rows="20" cols="50">result will be displayed here...</textarea>
```

Using Sieve of Eratosthenes link: [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#JavaScript)